# PHP / MYSQL - How to pass 2 or more results into a dynamic page?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, get

i am trying to help set up a website and I am struggling with how to pass 2 or more results into a dynamic page.

I currently have a selection page that pulls all the results from my database, using the following code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE subcategory IN('County','UK') AND dbtype ='bus' AND standard='yes' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50")
```

this then spits out the results as follows

```
$dynamicList .= li a href="moreinfo.php?id=' . $id . ' a
```

which works fine, however there are several versions of the same database, listed in consectutive id's like so:

```
1   UK Business Standard
2   UK Business Premium
3   UK Education Standard
4   UK Education Premium
5   UK Consumer Standard
6   UK Consumer Premium
```

Ideally i would like the user to select his location and then understand the difference between the packages - rather than have a location map plus a list of 100+ options which would be quite horrible to work through.

My question is, how would i pass 2 or more `id's` into the dynamic page. So if the user wanted the full UK education database, i would pass id3+1 allowing the end user to then see the difference in packages.

Comment: Could you reword your question please, it's hard to understand. What do you mean by passing two or more ids into a dynamic page, do you mean `something.php?like=this&and=this&id=another`?

Comment: as a query parameter? i.e.  ?id1=1&id2=3  giving params id1, id2, etc isnot wise. you something logical.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` then the result is an array of `id`s

```
$dynamicList .= 'li <a href="moreinfo.php?id[]=' . $id  . '">link text</a>';
```

then just append your other `ids`

```
$dynamiclist .= &'id[]=' . $nextid
```

so the final outcome would look like :

```
<a href="moreinfo.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3">link text</a>
```

then in PHP the values will within an array accessible using

```
print_r($_GET['id']);

array(
  'id' => array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3
  )
)
```